# how can Python see 12 cpus on a cluster where I got allocated 4 cores by LSF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, hpc

I access a Linux cluster where resources are allocated using LSF, which I think is a common tool and comes from Scali (http://www.scali.com/workload-management/high-performance-computing). In an interactive queue, I asked for and got the maximum number of cores: 4. But if I check how many cpus does Python's multiprocessing module see, the number is 12, the number of physical cores the node I was allocated to has. It looks like the multiprocessing module has problems respecting the bounds that LSF should/would impose. Is this a problem in LSF or Python?

```
[lsandor@iliadaccess03 peers_prisons]$ bsub -Is -n 4 -q interact sh
Job <7408231> is submitted to queue <interact>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on heroint5>>
sh-3.2$ python3
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Jun 13 2011, 09:20:03) 
[GCC 4.3.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> 
>>> multiprocessing.cpu_count()
12
```

Comment: I'm going to assume that python is looking at /proc/cpuinfo (or some other fancy method) to count the number of available cores. I suspect that LSF doesn't override this (or it may not be possible to).

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem, although your program should respect the amount of resources allocated to it by the queuing system, which may be considerably less than 100% as you have realized.  I don't believe LSF has OS-level hooks to enforce compliance, nor probably should it.

In the past I've seen this handled with a wrapper script.  One that that sets up a program and job simultaneously with the appropriate settings, then launches it.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am confused what else could I do then specifically ask for a number of processes in Pool, but (maybe unrelatedly?) I still got an error I cannot decipher, with many more workers than the 4 processes I preset, see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449099/how-come-i-have-more-threads-than-processes-i-asked-for-my-pool-in-py3k-multiproc>

Comment: It turns out the other error was unrelated. Though it would still be great to know if there is anything to do about multiprocessing and LSF together. Maybe I just ask for the same number of cores from both manually, and call it a day.

Comment: Yes, this is the strategy I was alluding to with the wrapper script story.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but expanding on the answer of @Paddy3118, the span specification is not needed. Instead, the environment variable `LSB_DJOB_NUMPROC` holds the number of allocated cores. At least it does with the LSF version available to me (9.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

If you submit to lsf using the -n option to state how many processors you want and then use request that the four processors are made available on the same host by using `span` like in the command below:

```
bsub -n 4 -R "span[hosts=1]" my_job
```

Then my_job is started with the following environment variables set which can be interrogated by your python script to set the number of sub-processes to start equal to the number assigned by LSF:

```
LSB_HOSTS= "hostA hostA hostA hostA"
LSB_MCPU_HOSTS="hostA 4"
```

(Or should the number of sub-processes be the number of processes allocated by LSF - 1 to account for the python script launching the sub-processes :-)